# Why does an error occur when installing tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length   url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/cudatoolkit-11.3.1-h59b6b97_2.conda   target_path: C:\Users\Rustem\anaconda3\pkgs\cudatoolkit-11.3.1-h59b6b97_2.conda   Content-Length: 571795436   downloaded bytes: 402453420 ,How fix?

Install Tesnroflow! and this error

Answer (score 0):

> CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length url:
> https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/cudatoolkit-11.3.1-h59b6b97_2.conda
> target_path:
> C:\Users\Rustem\anaconda3\pkgs\cudatoolkit-11.3.1-h59b6b97_2.conda
> Content-Length: 571795436 downloaded bytes: 402453420

The Error you are facing **CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length)** show tha the downloaded file for cudatoolkit-11.3.1-h59b6b97_2.conda is not correctly download or corrupted
First this is you need to ensure that your conda is up to date.

> conda install cudatoolkit=11.3.1

If you are still facing this issue then  clease conda cache and retry to download.Some time network issue can cause incomplete downloads.

you can also download it manually.[Anaconda](https://repo.anaconda.com/)

**Note:**- the path and version number according to your specific case.